# How a variable can be assigned with a function that's is invoked how does that works

Tags: javascript

I want to understand that how a variable can be assigned with a function that's invoked then call that variable again without showing undefined like this
    var today=moment();
    console.log(today)

```
             function moment(){
             console.log("hi")
             }
             var today = moment();
             console.log(today);`enter code here`
```

undefined

Comment: Your moment function does not returns anything ( return undefined implicitly ), which is being printed, where you're facing problem to understand ?

Comment: For the first question, look up function *return values* -- the variable is being assigned the return value. For the second part, you are not invoking that variable, but printing it out (invoking a function would require parentheses, like `today()`). It is undefined because of what @CodeManiac pointed out.

Comment: I still didn't understand what you said.

Answer (score 0):

So a little bit of explanation here, and then a possible solution.

Here is your function, with no return value.

```
function moment() {
   console.log("hi")
}
```

With your call `var today = moment();` You're executing / invoking your function, but because you're not returning anything, `var today = moment();` the function just executes so `today` stays as undefined.

If you do `var today = moment;` *notice lack of `()`* You're not invoking the function any more, you're passing a reference of the function to a new variable called `today`. And if you do `console.log(today)` you'll receive an output of `[Function: moment]`. It is this point you can execute the reference of the function now by calling `today()`

So your code would change to something like this.

```
function moment() {
   console.log("hi")
}
var today = moment;
today();
```